# Syntax help & Documentation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

It is a convenient feature to know.. is there a way to type in command in SQL Server Management Studio and get MS documentation/ info related to that funciton.

For e.g. something like sp_helptext DateDiff and it should list out the syntax of the function DateDiff and its various params ?

I remember seeing something of this sort but dont know the command and it is driving me nuts to google for little stuff everytime I need a syntax. Any info would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for syntax you can hover your cursor over the function.  If you need more info you can click inside the function and hit F1 for the MSDN site associated with the function.